# jQuery .each() won't iterate independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following piece of jQuery to apply span styles to the currency symbol and decimals of a bunch of monetary values.

```
$('td.priceBox').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<span class="price_currency price_element">' + $(this).html().substr(0, 1) // this styles the currency unit
    + "</span>" + $(this).html().substr(1, $(this).html().length-3) // this leaves the rounded value as is
    + '<span class="price_cents price_element">'
    + $(this).html().substr(-2)
    + "</span>") // this styles the decimals
});
```

This code works for the first value on the page, e.g. "$180.65," but then copies that value and replaces every value on the page with "$180.65".

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get this to iterate independently for each `td.priceBox`?

Note: The contents of `td.priceBox` are generated dynamically and I don't have access to them.  I cannot write the spans inline.

EDIT: I had another script designed to remove the decimal `$('.bannerContent td').html($('.bannerContent td').html().replace(".",""));`. This targeted the same td, but didn't identify it by its class. This successfully removed the decimal, but for some reason it broke the .each() method. Why?

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/n81tfpxL/)

Comment: Thanks. I traced the problem to another script.  Your JSFiddle pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: If you were able to solve your own problem and the solution might be relevant for other users, you can post your solution as an answer to your own question

Comment: I rolled back your edit - here on Stack Overflow we don't use things like "(Solved)" etc in titles.  As @arcyqwerty says, if you found an answer, feel free to post it and accept it as the solution.

Comment: If the problem isn't in the each but in another script then you should delete the question instead. If you want to post your own solution I would suggest updating the question title and issue

Comment: @Huangism I'm posting my own solution here per request and somebody can feel free to explain below.  I had another script designed to remove the decimal `$('.bannerContent td').html($('.bannerContent td').html().replace(".",""));`.  This targeted the same `td`, but didn't identify it by its class.  This successfully removed the decimal, but for some reason it broke the .each() method.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.bannerContent td').html($('.bannerContent td').html().replace(".",""));
```

This code is replacing all the `td`s with the HTML of the first one. That's because while `.html()` as a setter function applies to the whole jQuery set, as a getter it only runs on the first. If you place this inside your `.each()` and use `$(this)` it should work:

```
$('td.priceBox').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(".",""));
    $(this).html('<span class="price_currency price_element">' + $(this).html().substr(0, 1) // this styles the currency unit
    + "</span>" + $(this).html().substr(1, $(this).html().length-3) // this leaves the rounded value as is
    + '<span class="price_cents price_element">'
    + $(this).html().substr(-2)
    + "</span>") // this styles the decimals
});
```

For more information on how this works, see the jQuery `.html()` documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I think this also should work:

```
$('td.priceBox').each(function() {
var content       = $(this).html(),
    span          = $('<span />'),
    span_currency = span.addClass('price_currency price_element').html(content.substr(0, 1)),
    span_cents    = span.addClass('price_cents price_element').html(content.substr(-2));

    // Remove current content
    $(this).empty();

    // Add currency
    $(this).append(span_currency);

    // Add rounded value
    $(this).append(content.substr(1, (content.length - 3)));

    // Add cents
    $(this).append(span_cents);
```

});